# PHP file upload error (UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL) / $_FILES is null or has empty"tmp_name"

Tags: php, ios, file-upload, image-uploading

I have a quite common problem and spent hours to read some things about it, but I don't manage to fix it and I'm going crazy...

## Context

I have a website **where users can upload a picture to my server** (from iOS / Safari browser in the common case). The page with the upload form is [this one](http://iempty.tooliphone.net/en/upload-iphone-home-screen-image).

The backend is made with PHP (no framework). Front-end is HTML / Javascript. This is a quite old site I've made in 2010 so this is not "super sexy"! :-)

I made logs to monitor upload results, and I see that **about 30% of user uploads failed**... I guess this is not usual!

These errors are from 2 origins (same user trying to upload several times can have a mix of these 2 origins) :

- `$_FILES['myFormFieldName']` is **NULL**
- `$_FILES['myFormFieldName']` is NOT NULL but `$_FILES['myFormFieldName']['error']` is **3 (`UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL`)** with `$_FILES['xxx']['tmp_name']` and `$_FILES['xx']['type']` empty and `$_FILES['xxx']['size']` is "0"

These errors appears not to be deterministic...

- When I test myself (using the same image than a user having problems with uploading it) I have no problems
- I see in my logs that some users semms to always have problems with upload, but other don't.
- I also see that some users having problems managed to upload their file with siccess after several retry
- I had contact with one user having problems saying that he has the `Safari cannot open the page because network connection was lost` error page from Safari when trying to upload its picture (whenever he is in WiFi or mobile 3G/4G data)

---

## Code

HTML of form to upload the file
*(limit the user uploads to 35M from client-side)*

```
    <ul class="pageitem">
        <form name="empty-custom-native" 
              enctype="multipart/form-data" 
              action="/upload.php?method=nativeUpload" 
              method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="36700160" />
            <li class="button" >
                <input type="file" name="iosImageFILE" id="iosImageFILE"/>
            </li>
        </form>
        <li class="button directUrlButton" onclick="javascript:onclickNativeUploadForm();">
            <input type="button" value="Upload" />
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Javascript called by HTML 
*(used to check that the file input is not empty before submit the form)*

```
  function onclickNativeUploadForm(){
    if( document.getElementById('iosImageFILE').value=="" ){
      alert("Please choose an image FIRST !");
    } else{
      showPleaseWait();
      setTimeout(submitNativeUploadForm, 2000);
    }
  }

  function submitNativeUploadForm(){
      document.forms['empty-custom-native'].submit();
  }
```

PHP code managing the file upload (extract)

```php
<?php
if( isset($_FILES['iosImageFILE']) && !empty($_FILES['iosImageFILE']) ){
    $uploadStatus = $_FILES['iosImageFILE']['error'];
    if( $uploadStatus==0 ){
        // Copy source file to temp file
        if( !move_uploaded_file($_FILES['iosImageFILE']['tmp_name'], $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/".$userImageTemp) ) {
            throw new Exception("fileUploadCopy");
        }

    } else{
        if( $uploadStatus==1 ){ throw new Exception("fileUploadIniSize"); }
        else if( $uploadStatus==2 ){ throw new Exception("fileUploadFormSize"); }
        else if( $uploadStatus==3 ){ throw new Exception("fileUploadPartial"); } // THIS ERROR ...
        else if( $uploadStatus==4 ){ throw new Exception("fileUploadNoFile"); }
        else if( $uploadStatus==6 ){ throw new Exception("fileUploadNoTmpDir"); }
        else if( $uploadStatus==7 ){ throw new Exception("fileUploadCantWrite"); }
        else if( $uploadStatus==8 ){ throw new Exception("fileUploadExtension"); }
        else{
            throw new Exception("fileUploadSystem");
        }
    }
} else{
    throw new Exception("fileUploadUpload"); // ... OR THIS ERROR
}

// If anything was OK, we continue here with the uploaded file copied in our working dir to do some stuff with it...
?>
```

So in my case I have `fileUploadUpload` or `fileUploadPartial` exceptions.

---

## Investigations

#### Server-side (php.ini config)

I've checked the PHP environment variables dealing with file upload (with `ini_get` command) to check that I didn't exceed the max file size or max uploads number.

Everything seems fine, I have quite generous limits, `post_max_size` is gretaer than `upload_max_filesize`. `upload_tmp_dir` is empty by I guess this means that I use the default system `/tmp` dir?

Tell me if you see problems or other things to check.

Note: I don't have access to `php.ini`, but these values are fixed by my hosting provider (I am on a shared hosting).

```
file_uploads : '1'
upload_tmp_dir : ''
upload_max_filesize : '128M'
max_file_uploads : '20'
post_max_size : '130M'
max_execution_time : '300'
```

#### Client-side (HTML/JS code)

`MAX_FILE_SIZE` is less than the max file size allowed by my PHP server.

I used `enctype="multipart/form-data"` and `method="post"` as expected.

I don't do AJAX file upload, just using Javascript to check input file emptiness before submit the form with JS.

#### Server-side (PHP code)

When I debug the content of `$_FILES['iosImageFILE']` I get this for the `fileUploadPartial` error (and this is null for the `fileUploadUpload` error).

`iosImageFILE = {"name":"DD292A1C-9CBF-4843-9E1C-7C815593C67A.png","type":"","tmp_name":"","error":3,"size":0}`

#### Server-side (filesystem)

I tried to check the `/tmp` directory where the uploaded files are supposed to be, but I don't have access to it. I would like to check that it is not "full of old tmp files" but I guess not.

Indeed I made a PHP script to scan its content using `var_export(scandir('/tmp'))` and I only see some `sess_xxxxx` session files (about 7000 files).

#### Code upgrade

I've upgraded and enhanced my website to be in https (was non secured http before) and upgrade PHP version from 5.6 to 7.0). Without any change on file upload problems.

#### Firewall ?!?

I perhaps suspect a firewall problem with my hosting provider (I've read that it could block some things about file upload...). 
But they said me that there is no firewall activated on my host...

---

## Conclusion

I really don't know what to check next to investigate and find this problem.

Please note that almost everybody uploading files comes from iOS / Safari browser. I don't know if there would be the same problems from other OS or browsers...

I'm a front-end web developer and I must admint I'm not comfortable with this kind of problem.

**Any help appreciated!**

Comment: its mostly due to network partition

Comment: can you please be more explicit? I don't understand...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

End of the story : as suspected, this was a problem with my hosting provider (they took 1 month to solve it...)

I didn't managed to get more details, except that it was an "Apache configuration problem", and that it has a link with load balacing...

Comment: Would have been nice if your hosting provider gave more details on what changes they made. On a PHP web application we have, we also see a lot of partial upload errors and most (if not all?) of them seem to come from mobile devices. I have yet to solve our issue, but my conclusion so far is phones tend to bounce between different networks with mobile data and when this network change happens in the middle of an upload, it cuts the connection between the browser and web server and kills the upload itself.

Comment: IOS also seems to kill active ajax connections (if you upload using ajax) when the browser loses focus